# Find the shortest word, in a string of words

Tags: string, scala, shortest

I am doing a bit of Code-Wars Challenges again and I have a question about this particular one:

Task: " Given a string of words, return the length of the shortest word(s).

String will never be empty and you do not need to account for different data types."

I've looked up the answers available on SO and I've managed to create the program on my own based on foreign ideas.

The problem is it still does not produce the desired output.

I run- through the code and I think the problem lies with the variables, and my inability to assign to correct sections of the code.(although I may be wrong)

So below, I attach the code as well as the tests.

Hope, any of you can find the answer to the problem.

Cheers

```
object Shortest{
  def findShort(str:String):Int ={

    var smallestLength = 99
    var currentLength = 0

    for(word <- str.split("")) {
      currentLength = 0

      for(letter <- word){
        currentLength +=1
      }

      if(currentLength < smallestLength)
        smallestLength = currentLength         
    }
    smallestLength            
  } 
}
```

Here are the tests:

Test Results:

ShortestTest
 findShort(bitcoin take over the world maybe who knows perhaps) should return 3

Test Failed
1 was not equal to 3
 Stack Trace
Completed in 45ms
 findShort(turns out random test cases are easier than writing out basic ones) should return 3
Test Failed

1 was not equal to 3
 Stack Trace
Completed in 1ms
 findShort(lets talk about javascript the best language) should return 3
Test Failed
1 was not equal to 3
 Stack Trace
Completed in 1ms
 findShort(i want to travel the world writing code one day) should return 1
 findShort(Lets all go on holiday somewhere very cold) should return 2
Test Failed

1 was not equal to 2
 Stack Trace
Completed in 1ms
 findShort(Steem Dogecoin 21inc Dash MadeSafeCoin) should return 4
Test Failed

1 was not equal to 4
 Stack Trace
Completed in 1ms
 findShort(Bitcoin Lisk) should return 4
Test Failed
1 was not equal to 4
 Stack Trace
Completed in 1ms
 findShort(ProofOfStake Ripple) should return 6
Test Failed

1 was not equal to 6
 Stack Trace
 findShort(ProofOfWork Dogecoin BTC Classic Dash Ripple ProofOfWork) should return 3
Test Failed

1 was not equal to 3
 Stack Trace
Completed in 1ms
 findShort(LiteCoin Bitcoin LiteCoin Bitcoin Waves Waves Bitcoin Dash Ripple Ripple Ethereum Classic Factom LiteCoin Factom Waves Factom) should return 4
Test Failed

1 was not equal to 4
 Stack Trace
Completed in 2ms
 findShort(Bitcoin Waves MadeSafeCoin DarkCoin ProofOfStake Classic BTC) should return 3
Test Failed

1 was not equal to 3
 Stack Trace
Completed in 1ms
 findShort(ProofOfStake Waves Ethereum Ethereum Ripple LiteCoin Steem Classic LiteCoin Ripple ProofOfStake Steem Monero Dogecoin Factom) should return 5
Test Failed

Comment: What happens if your input has only substrings of size 100 or more?

Comment: And if you'd like a one-liner: `def f(s:String) = s.split(" ").map(_.length).filter(_ > 0).min`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is ok actually, all you need to change is `str.split("")` to `str.split(" ")` (note the space).

Here is a way to do it relying on built-in method:

```
def findShort(wordsString: String): Int = {
  val wordsArray = wordsString.split(" ")
  wordsArray.minBy(_.length).length
}

println(findShort("LiteCoin Bitcoin LiteCoin Bitcoin Waves Waves Bitcoin Dash Ripple Ripple Ethereum Classic Factom LiteCoin Factom Waves Factom"))
// Display 4
println(findShort("Bitcoin Waves MadeSafeCoin DarkCoin ProofOfStake Classic BTC"))
// Display 3
```

And here a version that use `foldLeft`, if you don't want to rely on built in method:

```scala
def length(word: String): Int =
  word.foldLeft(0){case (acc, _) => acc + 1}

def findShort(str:String):Int = {

   str.split(" ").foldLeft(99){ case (smallestLength, word) =>
      val currentLength = length(word)
      if(currentLength < smallestLength)
         currentLength
       else smallestLength
   }
}
```

Comment: The `isEmpty` test is unnecessary because `split` will always return a non-empty `Array`.

Comment: Ahh, ok I've just added the space,and everything works perfect.

Comment: Thanks for the two examples with the different methods though, that gives me some other  view at it.